# I have two combo Boxes where I want users to calculate a total time for a process

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

//Currently the format of the comboxes is in hh:mm, and I know I'm not converting them correctly into a DateTime.Parse from the comboBoxes, any help would be great!!

```
    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string start = comboBox2.SelectedItem;
        starttime = DateTime.Parse(start);

    }

    private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string end = comboBox3.SelectedItem;
        endtime = DateTime.Parse(end);

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double z;

        z = endtime - starttime;
        textBox1.Text = z.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: you probably need **ParseExact** instead of Parse. From the official docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string format = "hh:mm"
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(comboBox.Text, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Try this to parse into dateTime :)

By the way, ComboBox.SelectedItem does not return a string, so make sure you call SelectedItem.ToString() if you are not going to read the Text property.

Comment: I got the following error when applying that: The name 'CultureInfo' does not exist in the current context

Comment: using System.Globalization;

Comment: Great cheers, I got it working using the following but by changing the z variable to TimeSpan as well, thanks for the help!